# how to save existing pdf file in NSDocumentDirectory in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, nsdocumentdirectory

I have one pdf file and I want to save that file using `NSDocumentDirectory` and retrieve it.how do i convert pdf file into `NSData` so that I can save. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you are creating the pdf file?

Comment: R u generation pdf using QLPreviewViewController or you are dragging the pdf file into ur project..!

Answer (score 1):

Brad,

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

This is not a site where people give you solutions to your problems "out of whole cloth". You need to show what you have attempted, and the specific places where you are stuck.

You say you "have one pdf file". Is it a file on disk somewhere, in memory, or what? If it's already on disk then you can use the file manager to copy it to the documents directory. Take a look in the Xcode docs under NSFileManager and read the class reference. There are tons of useful methods for creating and copying files.

You say "..how do i convert pdf file into NSData so that I can save." Erm, if it's a file, why do you need to convert it to NSData in order to save it? It's already a file.

NSData has methods for creating a data object with the contents of a file (`dataWithContentsOfFile` and `dataWithContentsOfURL`) as well as methods for writing an NSData object to a file (again using a path or an NSURL, like the `dataWith...` methods)

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have PDF file so i guess it will be a ready file.

Now in that case you don't need to put it in document directory. Just put it into your resources folder where you placed images & other files.

After that to read that pdf file Simply do this:

```
UIWebView *myweb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
myweb.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[myweb loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:myweb];
```

Hope it will work for you.